# Android java : Dealing whith xml's parsed String

Tags: java, android, string, xmlpullparser

I have an xml which Text looks like this :

```
<LINE>here is some text, it is going,going, and then return is pressed
and the text is going from the next line</LINE>
```

now when I do :

```
    XmlPullParcer xpp;
//then all the parcing, try/catch stuff, finding needed tag
    String s=xpp.getText();
    myTextView.setText(s);
```

(of course, I cut all the code, but you got the idea)

what I see on the screen is not one solid line with no formatting as I wish, but the same two-line text

So, what I see on the screen is :

here is some text, it is going,going, and then return is pressed

and the text is going from the next line

and I want :

here is some text, it is going,going, and then return is pressed and but text is going in one line

please tell me how can I process my String s so it can be shown in a TextView in one line

Comment: apparently there is a line feed in your text. i don't see what the issue is.

Comment: If I understand correctly you require the text to be displayed on one line? If yes, then in the layout file you can set the textview's width to match_parent.

Comment: I don't want a line to break. I need the text in one line from one tag. I don't want it to be broken into several lines because on screen it is a mess

Comment: VikramV, this doesn't help in any way. The problem is in String - I need to prosess it some way for the entire text doesn't look ugly on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the line in XML itself is having a line feed or carriage return. So try to replace them with empty string via String replace method. You can refer to link below for more details:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum

Also make sure the TextView in layout has singleline attribute set to true and layout_width set to match_parent.

Comment: I don't want it to be single line TextView, I want a String go in one line. You mean Pattern.quote(String) method? it return me a text having \Q in the beginning and \E in the end